How can we promote the site and reach out to industry experts?
The site should soon be coming into a Public Beta period where anyone can sign up and use the site.
How can we spread awareness to experts, researchers and practitioners in the cognitive science fields?


Get listed in the directory: http://www.psychology.org/ perhaps under one of these categories: http://www.psychology.org/links/Resources/
Perhaps see whether any of the people in this list of psychology bloggers are interested in reviewing the site
Reddit 

This has awesome potential, but be careful with how anyone does this; self-promotion is seriously frowned upon on Reddit: it's also sometimes better if the person posting the link has at lest some existing "karma"; A good strategy is to share questions and answers that you think would really interest the target subreddit, and think of a good title. If your link gets completely down voted or receives negative comments, then don't post another link to that subreddit for a while.
http://www.reddit.com/r/cogsci/
http://www.reddit.com/r/mathpsych/
http://www.reddit.com/r/psychology/
http://www.reddit.com/r/AcademicPsychology/

When it goes public beta, I'll post a review on my blog (it has around 650 readers). Hopefully any of the other users of the site that maintain a blog can do the same.
I haven't used Quora much, but there are communities there that might be interested:

http://www.quora.com/Cognitive-Science
http://www.quora.com/Psychology



Besides standard tools as Facebook, Google+, Twitter and the f2f it is good to spread the word in places people may be really interested, e.g.:

on a cognitive science-related blog if someone has one,
on a webpage of a research group in cognitive science (or even better: on that of the faculty), 
through academic mailing lists.


For a lot of people, Wikipedia is the first place to start their searching. We might want to increase our exposure, by acting as sources for wikipedia to cite. If there is some wikipedia article that is missing important information (or citations) and we have a definitive answer on our site providing such information, it might be good to add a reference (with appropriate links) from wikipedia to the answers on this site.

Would the wikipedians consider a Q&A site a reliable source? I would doubt that...

cstheory.SE is referenced on wikipedia. I think it just depends on the quality of content.

Wikipedia would probably want the primary source, wouldn't they? Our answers are generally the secondary source, citing primary material

@BenBrocka usually a good answer (to a good question) combines many different primary sources that are tangentially related into a sort of mini-survey that answers the question. But I agree, most of the 'single source' answers are no good.

For instance, if there is a probabilistic (or bayesian) models of cognition article on wikipedia, this question would be good to cite in the "shortcomings and criticism" section.
